# Possible to have a 100% wide div but limit it's contents to a set max-width?

Tags: html, css, width

I know this can easily be done with 2 divs, having the outer one be set to 100% width, and the inner one be set to max-width 1000px for example.

I'm just curious if it can be done with only one div instead of two.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, this is possible,

because an html element is never 'just 100%'. It has to be 100% of something else. Either it is 100% related to the first element containing it that has position relative, absolute or fixed. Or 100% related to the window.

The max-width will take over from the width when the surrounding container (this can be the window) grows larger than 1000px.

Check the snippet below. if you resize the window in full window view, there will be no scrollbars.

```css
.testwidth {
  background: yellow;
  height: 100px;
  max-width: 1000px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="testwidth">heyho</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, but this isn't quite the answer I'm after.  What I'm wondering is if it's possible to have the yellow background of the div always be 100% of the width, while only allowing the contents of the div to be limited to 1000px.  Does that make sense?

Comment: No that is not possible. You cannot separate the contents from its element (for styling purposes).

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes i need to do this and i use "calc padding". For example:

```
.element {
  width: 100%; 
  padding-right: calc(100% - 1000px); 
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Thou i wouldn't recommend using this as it's not very friendly for responsive designs as you need to set quite an amount of media queries to adapt it.

Comment: Not if you use em! :) Really good for responsive headings that you want to stay in a certain shape where possible but wrap where needed. `calc(100% - 25em)` for example :)

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example based on @Erik Ragnar Eliasson's answer. Toggle to full page to see the effect.

When the page width goes below the content width, the padding calc value goes negative, but as negative padding values are invalid, the padding will be set to 0, and the content width will be back to the width of the page.

To get the content centre aligned, divide the value of the calc between left and right padding.

The inner div in the example is only to show the effect, it doesn't contribute to the layout.

```css
.outer {
  --content-width: 1000px;
  
  background-color: blue;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding-right: calc(100% - var(--content-width));
  width: 100%;
}

.inner {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner">
    Contents here
  </div>
</div>
```